# $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{a+b\sin\theta}$ where $a,b>0$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dfrac{d\theta}{a+b\sin\theta}$ where $a,b>0$

Supposedly a very simple residue theorem problem but I'm stuck with the pole(s).

Let $z=e^{i\theta}$ and $d\theta=\frac{dz}{iz}$. Then,
$$\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{D}}\frac{dz}{\left[a+b\left(\frac{z-z^{-1}}{2i}\right)\right]iz}&=\int_{\mathbb{D}}\frac{2idz}{(2ai+bz-bz^{-1})iz}\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{D}}\frac{2dz}{bz^2+2aiz-b}
\end{align*}$$

By quadratic formula, we can deduce that we have pole at $$z=\frac{-ai\pm\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}{b}$$
But I'm having trouble figuring out which, of the two is in fact in the unit circle. All we have is $a>0$ and $b>0$ and I feel like it could go so many different ways depending on the actual values that they take. Can anyone help me to proceed?

Comment: @metamorphy right! That was my initial thought too, until I actually tried to get my hands dirty with it. May be I’m doing something wrong.

Comment: @metamorphy edited!

Comment: Now it should be easy for you (the poles are purely imaginary, one inside, the other outside).

Comment: @metamorphy I feel like I’m still having trouble computing for different relations between $a$ and $b$ these for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a\leqslant b$ the integral clearly diverges.

Otherwise, as you've shown, the poles are
$$z=\frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b}i,$$
and the pole with "$+$" is inside the unit circle. It remains to compute the residue.

Comment: What does it mean by integral diverges? And how do we know that?

Comment: It means "the integrand is not integrable" - because $a+b\sin\theta$ reaches $0$ in this case.